# CSS media query not working as expected at breakpoint

Tags: html, css, media-queries

CSS has a breakpoint set at 768px. When below or over the breakpoint, objects will stretch accordingly. Exactly at 768px some objects won't stretch. How is that?
Take a look [here](http://www.acornhouse.school/) at the first row below the initial slider: at 768px, the picture will not stretch to fill the available width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inconsistent queries.

The `padding-left` of the `panel-grid-cell` is set to `0` when `max-width: 767px` not `768px`.

```
// custom-style.css:30164 (when un-minified)
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .thim-welcome-university>.panel-grid-cell:nth-child(2) {
        padding-left: 0!important;
    } 
}
```

Modify that to `768px` :)

Comment: Mate, thanks a lot. How can I list all the media queries in effect?

Comment: You are welcome. I am using DevTools from Chrome. Activate the first button on the top right and you will see some changes to the window. You will find there some extra settings.

Comment: I see that the stylesheet has a lot of 767 settings... Are those wrong?

Comment: Well I have removed the .thim-welcome-university and it works! Thanks!

Comment: I am glad you got it to work. I was out with a friend and was afk :))